# VIM how to select/copy column n from line x to y

Tags: vim

I use visual block to copy a specific column in some ranges (say lines *x* to *y*). I wonder if there is a simpler way to accomplish the same task.

Also, after I copy those lines, I would like to cut and paste them horizontally. Is it possible? It's sort of annoying to do *J*, especially if the number of lines is large.

For example, **File A** (btw both files are open in the split window) is

```
............
sadsa asds  dog 
sadsa asds  cat
sadsa asds  me
sadsa asds  you
...........
```

And I want to copy 4 rows in the 3rd column to **File B**,  which may already contain data. Say I want to copy this data on line 30, this way (line numbers are hypothetical):

```
   ...............
   29.  other data
   30.  dog cat me you
   31.  other data
   ................
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would paste it and use 4J, 5J, 20J etc. depending on how many lines there are. Is this still too annoying to do?

**EDIT:** Ahh, I see how this would be pretty painful. I played around with this a bit and made a macro that eases the pain quite a bit. It essentially automates what MBO suggests below.

```
moGo^[pVGJdd'op
```

Paste that into a vim buffer, replace `^[` with an actual escape character (With default keybindings, go in insert mode, press CTRL-v, then press ESC.

Now highlight that macro, and press `"py`

Now you can play the macro with `@p`

Copy the vertical 'dog cat me you' string from one file, go into the other and position the cursor where you want it, then push @p and it should work!

**RE-EDIT:** Peter Rincker's answer is far better than mine, and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: one problem with this is when  I have to paste in the middle of the file already containing other data, it merges old data which  I don't want

Comment: @vehomzzz You can paste it at the end of the file, join and then cut-n-paste where you want it to be

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do it =) thx How would you copy those lines?

Comment: vehomzz - I edited my post again, Peter Rincker posted an answer that has a much better, more general solution for this.

Answer (score 5):

Copy the text from file A with visual bock mode by hitting `Ctrl-V` at the top left corner of the text chunk then moving the cursor to opposite corner of the text chunk then hit `y`. Move to file B where you want to paste your chunk of text, then execute the following:

```
:put
:'[,']join
```

`:put` will paste text from a register in line mode, including visual block yanked text.

`:join` will join lines together just like the `J` command.

`'[` and `']` are marks set at the beginning and ending of a change.

`:'[,']join` will join from the beginning of pasted text to the end of the pasted text.

For more information see:

```
:h :put
:h :j
```